# Adapt-Strap and Column Text Alignment

Tags: css, angularjs

Using Adapt-Strap ad-table-lite in AngularJS. I need to have some numbered columns aligned to the right - Everything defaults to left alignment. If I can't align the columns, adapt-strap is useless to me. Any ideas?

I've tried adding column header and data templates with divs and spans, with classes and styles and nothing sticks. Only adding some padding-left does anything, and it would be a pain to align columns that way.

Answer (score 0):

There were no built-in solutions, so I added a "columnAlign" property to the columnDefinitions, then added support for them in the adapt-strap.tpl.js file. I added it to the same place that responds to the width attribute. I added it to the header as well. While I was at it, I made the sort icon's visibility optional as well.